# Android studio: IDE internal errors

Tags: android-studio

After opening the Android Studio I see error for IDE.

Here are error details:

```
AnalyticsSettings call failed

java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\androidO1\analytics.settings (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:344)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettingsData.saveSettings(AnalyticsSettings.kt:454)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettingsData.saveSettings$default(AnalyticsSettings.kt:447)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings$saveSettings$1.invoke(AnalyticsSettings.kt:435)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings$saveSettings$1.invoke(AnalyticsSettings.kt:434)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.runIfAnalyticsSettingsUsable(AnalyticsSettings.kt:100)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.saveSettings(AnalyticsSettings.kt:434)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.ConsentDialog$Companion.showConsentDialogIfNeeded(ConsentDialog.kt:189)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.ConsentDialog.showConsentDialogIfNeeded(ConsentDialog.kt)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidStudioInitializer.setupAnalytics(AndroidStudioInitializer.java:52)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidStudioInitializer.componentsInitialized(AndroidStudioInitializer.java:40)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$callAppInitialized$1$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:485)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1375)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.awaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:436)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(ForkJoinTask.java:828)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$prepareStart$4$future$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:232)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
```

I checked and I don't have such folder as D:\androidO1\analytics.settings. But the question is - how do I change this path and to what do I change it?

Before I was unable to use Android studio due to not enough space of my C drive. Thus I have tried to move it to D drive and tried multiple instructions available online. Maybe it broke my configurations and right now even if I re-install android studio it is throwing this error.

In any case, right now my Android studio is located on C drive. I have freed some space and gave up the idea about moving it to D drive.